# Would hot water induce current in a copper wire via the movement of the molecules from the heat alone?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, energy, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

I am a novice, so please excuse the naivety of my question.

- Would hot water induce current in a copper wire via the movement of the molecules from the heat alone?

An additional follow up if that isn't complete nonsense.

- Would the electrical resistance in copper produce and transfer some heat back to the water continuing the cycle?

Comment: Why would they? And why hot water? The molecules move in cold water too.

Comment: electric current is due to the motion of electrons . http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html . molecules are bound on the lattice and might vibrate but cannot "move". https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-molecule-and-vs-lattice/

Comment: Welcom Michael to Physics SE. You seem to be asking about  [thermoelectric effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect).  Electric current could be driven by temperature differences, but not by heating the wire uniformly, e.g. see ["Seebeck Effect in a homogenous material"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/741295/145491).

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!

The thought was that the magnetic field produced from each H20 molecule would move electrons as they moved around the copper wire. 

And the movement would come from the kinetic energy of the molecules.

But, after some more thought, it seem movement of a UNIFORM magnetic field would be required to move electrons within the wire in any significant way.

Comment: @nasu Answering directly here.

1. The magnetic fields produced by the individual molecules moving over the copper.
2. You are right! The thought was hot water has more kinetic energy.