# Single metal Seebeck effect in a ring in the presence of a magnetic field

Tags: metals, non-equilibrium, thermoelectricity, aharonov-bohm

According to the usual Seebeck effect, you can make a loop of wire with two different metals, apply a temperature difference between two opposite sites of the ring and measure a current. See picture
[image]

taken from [here](https://www.eeeguide.com/thermocouple-connection/).

An answer to this question [Seebeck effect and the need for two conductors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407213/seebeck-effect-and-the-need-for-two-conductors) claims that the difference in metals is not necessary, you can have a single metal you just need to break the symmetry so that you select the current to go clockwise or anti-clockwise.

(One reason to doubt this statement is that we could make the distances between the two temperature contacts asymmetric with respect to the circumference and this in principle should not generate any currents)

My question is, in a single metal loop, with a point on the loop at temperature $T_1$ and the antipode point in the loop at temperature $T_2<T_1$, would an external static magnetic field (perpendicular to the plane of the ring) produce a current? And if so does this lead to some kind of out of equilibrium Aharonov-Bohm effect (where current only is created at certain value of the magnetic field) without a battery?

Comment: related effects: the Righi-LeDuc effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_Hall_effect and the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nernst_effect  but I do not think "AB" has anything to do with them; and I do not think that you can have "Seebeck" with a single metal as the contact potential is crucial as far as I understand it.

Comment: @hyportnex, you can certainly have the Seebeck effect taking place in a single material. If you actually want to measure the Seebeck voltage using the archaic way of using leads with a voltmeter, you have to use a different material, otherwise you would measure 0 voltage, i.e. you wouldn't be able to measure it. But you're not obliged to measure the Seebeck voltage that way.

Comment: Question unclear. What do you mean by magnetic field? A static one produced by a permanente magnet for instance? Or a time varying one?

Comment: @untreated_paramediensis_karnik constant magnetic field, an alternating would produce a current